# Solving name-clash in cpp file of a class

Tags: c++, namespaces, scope, name-clash

I would like to call the unscoped function "bar" from "somelib" within the "bar" method of Foo.

```
// .h
class Foo
{
    int bar();
};

// .cpp
#include "Foo.h"
#include <somelib> // contains unscooped function bar()

int Foo::bar()
{
    return bar(); // unwanted recursive function
}
```

---

One way to solve it is to make use of a helper function, such as "bar_helper"

```
// .cpp
#include "Foo.h"
#include <somelib> // contains unscooped function bar()

// unnamed namespace
namespace
{
    int bar_helper()
    {
        return bar(a);
    }
}

int Foo::bar()
{
    return bar_helper();
}
```

---

- Can it be made more pretty?
- Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the non-member `bar` function is in the global scope, you can use the scoping operator `::`:

```
int Foo::bar()
{
    return ::bar();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Be explicit about the scope, in this case, the global one:

```
return ::bar();
       ^^
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I had to choose Joachim's answer since I liked his explanation a tiny bit better, however I have to commend you for answering a few seconds earlier than him.